# Ruby/Rails method to return a removed hash entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm wanting to be able to remove an item from a hash, but return the value of the removed item upon removal. I cannot seem to find a single method that does this.

For example:

```
opts = {
  value: 1,
  checked: true,
  label: {...}
}

value = opts.METHOD(:value)      # -> `value` now equals 1
checked = opts.METHOD(:checked)  # -> `checked` now equals true
                                 # -> `opts` now equals { label: {...} }
```

Is there a single method like this? I was hoping `slice` would work somehow, but it only returns the values that remain, not what was taken out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `hash#delete`. For example say you have the following hash.

```
hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2}
```

Simply use the delete method on the key of your choice

```
hash.delete(:b)
=> 2
```

If you call `hash` again, you will find the value disappeared

```
hash
=> {:a => 1}
```

Check out the ruby documentation here.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete

> Deletes and returns a key-value pair from hsh whose key is equal to key.
>
> If the key is not found, returns the default value. If the optional code block is given and the key is not found,
> pass in the key and return the result of block.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't think about looking at `delete` because I didn't think about it returning the deleted value. This is perfect, thanks!